# How to link two rows in SQL Server from different tables by some ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables:

- `Accounts` (UserID, Username, Password, Email)
- `UserInfo` (UserID, Wins, Losses, Draws)

My desired functionality:

- When I insert a new row into `Accounts`, I would like to create a corresponding row in the `UserInfo` table that defaults the `Wins`, `Losses`, and `Draws` columns to `0`.
- When an `Account` wins a game, I would like to update its row in the corresponding `UserInfo` table.

Basically, I know that there must be a unique identifier `ID` that the database creates for each row. I would like that unique identifier to be identical across both tables. `UserID` should have no real purpose other than being a unique number

I have tried many different `CREATE` commands, none have worked. This is what I have now:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Accounts] 
(
    [UserID]    INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Username]  NVARCHAR (256) NOT NULL,
    [Passwords] NVARCHAR (256) NOT NULL,
    [Email]     NVARCHAR (256) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserID] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserInfo] 
(
    [UserID]  INT NOT NULL,
    [Wins]    INT NOT NULL,
    [Losses]  INT NOT NULL,
    [RankLvl] INT NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY ([UserID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Accounts] ([UserID])
);
```

When I try to run this code (C#):

```
public void addNewUserAccount(string username, string password, string email)
{
    executeCommand(string.Format(@"Insert Into
                                  Accounts(Username, Passwords, Email)
                                  Values ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}')", username, password, email));
}

public void addNewUserDefaultStats()
{
    executeCommand(string.Format(@"Insert Into
                                  UserInfo(Wins, Losses, RankLvl)
                                  Values (0, 0, 0)"));
}
```

I get:

> Unhandled Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'User', table 'D:\DROPBOX\Game\BIN\DEBUG\DB.MDF.dbo.UserInfo'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Should I not include a `UserID` column in both tables? Is that something I let the database take care of? Using a locally stored `.mdf` file

Comment: Well, the `UserID` in your `UserInfo` table is defined as `NOT NULL` without a default constraint --> you **must** provide a value for it when you insert a new row into `UserInfo` - simple as that ....

Comment: Sounds like `UserInfo` should be a view on top of a `Game` table that computes the number of wins, losses, and draws.

Answer (score 0):

You can either insert rows to each table successively they will both have the same ID if they have the same increment value.
Another solution to add a 'userame' colum into the UserInfo table or you can add a column called account_id which will be the inserted id into the accounts table.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Accounts] (
    [ID]    INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Username]  NVARCHAR (256) NOT NULL,
    [Passwords] NVARCHAR (256) NOT NULL,
    [Email]     NVARCHAR (256) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserID] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserInfo] (
    [ID] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [AccountsID]  INT NOT NULL,
    [Wins]    INT NOT NULL,
    [Losses]  INT NOT NULL,
    [RankLvl] INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY ([AccountID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Accounts] ([ID])
);

[select * from Accounts inner join UserInfo on Accounts.ID = UserInfo.AccountsID]
```

This is the form I typically see in well designed database. If you want them to share the same identity, put all the information on the same table.

Comment: Thank you Bryce! Is it a better design practice to create two seperate tables for something like an account for a game and the scores? Or would it be safe/good design to have all information inside of one table?

Comment: If all you are doing is updating a current tally of wins and losses there is no good reason not to simply.
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Accounts] (
    [ID]    INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Username]  NVARCHAR (256) NOT NULL,
    [Passwords] NVARCHAR (256) NOT NULL,
    [Email]     NVARCHAR (256) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserID] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserInfo] (
    [ID] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [AccountsID]  INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY ([AccountID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Accounts] ([ID])
);